# Rails - Javascript - Triggering data behaviour onchange

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following buttons that perform as intended and close / open the desired lightbox:

```
<a data-behaviour="closing-lightbox" href="#edit-class" class="button">Edit Details</a>
<a data-behaviour="closing-lightbox" href="#move-class-year" class="button">Move Class</a>
<a data-behaviour="closing-lightbox" href="#delete-single-class" class="button button--error">Delete Class</a>
```

I'm trying to get the same behaviour to occur when a dropdown is changed:

```
<%= f.input_field :file, as: :file, data: {behaviour: 'file-upload closing-lightbox'}, href: '#upload-csv', class: 'file-upload-hide' %>
```

This doesn't trigger, and neither does assigning the 'closing-lightbox' function to the onchange attribute. Is there any way for me to combine the data-behaviour and the onchange attributes so that it is called on change?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#csv_file").on("change", function(){
    var box = document.getElementById("upload-csv")
    box.style.display = "block";
  })
});
```

Is there any way for me to call the data-behaviour method closing-lightbox (is it a method?) inside this function, with the href attribute as well? Thanks in advance again!

Answer (score 1):

[Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) are simply a valid way to attach any arbitrary data to an element.

So no - its not a method. You can attach event handlers to elements with a specific data attribute by using a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
$(document).on('click', '*[data-behaviour="closing-lightbox"]', function(){
  console.log('Eureka!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-behaviour="closing-lightbox">Click me</button>
```

But using classes instead to attach behavior is actually [a bit faster](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall) (as well as simpler) as it uses `document.getElementsByClassName` vs `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Thank you so much my javascript skills are pretty horrendous!

Comment: I accepted too early :( Copying and pasting the above doesn't console log, however removing the data-behvaiour part does

Comment: The code here does attach an event handler to any element (the * means any type of element) with the attribute `data-behaviour="closing-lightbox"`. Are you sure it's not an unrelated error?

Comment: I believe so - leaving it as: $(document).on('click',  function(){
  console.log('Eureka!');
});
logs to console, but if I copy paste the above it doesn't